# Cant set AWS credentials in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working on a cloud project using NodeJS. 
I have to run EC2 instances so have done a `npm install aws-sdk`.

I believe we have to add our credentials now before we run the application?

I could not aws folder so I have created a folder and added the credentials in the `credentials.txt` file.

`C:\Users\jessig\aws`

I keep getting this error:

```
{ [TimeoutError: Missing credentials in config]
  message: 'Missing credentials in config',
  code: 'CredentialsError',
```

I tried setting the Access key and secret key in environment variables but still get the same error..

Not sure why I cant find the `\.aws\credentials` (Windows) folder..

Can anyone please help?

Comment: can u add some sample code of what you've tried?

Answer (score 25):

As Frederick mentioned hardcoding is not an AWS recommended standard, and this is not something you would want to do in a production environment. However, for testing purpose, and learning purposes, it can be the simplest way.

Since your request was specific to AWS EC2, here is a small example that should get you started.

To get a list of all the methods available to you for Node.js reference this  [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html).

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk'); 

AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
AWS.config.accessKeyId = "accessKey";
AWS.config.secretAccessKey = "secretKey";
AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";

var ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

var params = {
  InstanceIds: [ /* required */
    'i-4387dgkms3',
    /* more items */
  ],
  Force: true
};
ec2.stopInstances(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I think I'd have a better chance at guessing the syntax than finding a single working example that doesn't require 5 other prerequisite set-ups in the AWS documentation.

Comment: Note that using `AWS.config.accessKeyId=` or `AWS.config.secretAccessKey=` is now deprecated

Comment: Would be nice to know what the alternative approach is.

Comment: Amazing how unintuitive this is. I'm sticking with the deprecated method.

Answer (score 19):

I used the following programmatic way, combined with the popular npm config module (which allows different config files for development vs production, etc.):

```
const config = require('config');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const accessKeyId = config.get('AWS.accessKeyId');
const secretAccessKey = config.get('AWS.secretAccessKey');
const region = config.get('AWS.region');
AWS.config.update(
    {
        accessKeyId,
        secretAccessKey,
        region
    }
);
```

And the json config file, e.g. development.json, would look like:

```
   {
       "AWS": {
           "accessKeyId": "TODO",
           "secretAccessKey": "TODO",
           "region": "TODO"
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 6):

There are [multiple ways](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/guide/node-configuring.html) to configure the sdk to work with node js

> There are a few ways to load credentials. Here they are, in order of
>   recommendation:
>
> - Loaded from IAM roles for Amazon EC2 (if running on EC2),
> - Loaded from the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials),
> - Loaded from environment variables,
> - Loaded from a JSON file on disk,
> - Hardcoded in your application

Although the hardcoded one is not recommended.

If you want to use a shared credentials files, on windows it would be

```
C:\Users\jessig\.aws\credentials
```

(note the `.` before aws). Your file should be something like

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = your_access_key
aws_secret_access_key = your_secret_key
```

Comment: what if I use codestar? I cannot use a file on disk

Comment: @Frederic, I am on mac. There is no folder at  ```~/.aws/``` https://imgur.com/j4FlAin

Comment: @bibscy it means you did not configure aws cli tool yet

Comment: @FredericHenri  ```(base) bogdanmac:~ iliebogdanbarbulescu$ brew install awscli
Warning: awscli 2.0.46 is already installed and up-to-date
To reinstall 2.0.46, run `brew reinstall awscli`
(base) bogdanmac:~ iliebogdanbarbulescu$```, but still there is no ```~/.aws/``` directory

Comment: @bibscy not syaing to install but configure, check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html

Answer (score 3):

Adding `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey` in the config for AWS is deprecated as of today. As the AWS Docs for SDK for Node.js states:

> The SDK automatically detects AWS credentials set as variables in your environment and uses them for SDK requests. This eliminates the need to manage credentials in your application. The environment variables that you set to provide your credentials are:

- `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`
- `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`
- `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` (Optional)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html

---

You may want to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to load those environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

The AWS credentials can be set as ENVIRONMENT VAR in the running container.
You would either add the following two ENVIRONMENT VAR directly:

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID

AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

or set these ENVIRONMENT VAR programmatically within NODE as

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config = new AWS.Config();
process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "AKIA************L55A"
process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "Ef*******+C5LrtOroSj**********yNE"
AWS.config.region = "us-east-2"
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/loading-node-credentials-environment.html